# Is there an algebraically normal function from $\mathbb{Z}^{2}$ to $\{ 0 , 1\}$?

Tags: probability, algebraic-geometry, normal-distribution, algebraic-curves

Let $\gamma : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be a real algebraic curve.
Let $r \geq 0$ and $I \subset \mathbb{R} $ then $\gamma_{r} (I)= \{a \in \mathbb{R}^{2} : \exists b \in \gamma(I), d(a,b)\leq r  \}  $
Let $\gamma_{\mathbb{r,Z}}$ be the set $\gamma_{r} (\mathbb{R}) \cap \mathbb{Z}^{2}$.
Let $t >0$ and $\gamma_{r,\mathbb{Z}}^{t}$ be the set $\gamma_{r}([-t,t]) \cap \mathbb{Z}^{2}$.

Let $\omega : \mathbb{Z}^{2} \to \{ 0 , 1\}$ be a function.

**Definition** :  $\omega$ is **algebraically normal** if for all algebraic curve $\gamma$ and $\forall r \geq 0$ such that $\vert \gamma_{\mathbb{r,Z}} \vert  = \infty$ : 
$$ \lim\limits_{t \to \infty}
\frac{\vert \omega^{-1}(0) \cap \gamma_{\mathbb{r,Z}}^{t} \vert}{\vert \gamma^{t}_{\mathbb{r,Z}} \vert} = \frac{1}{2}
$$

> Is there exist such an *algebraically normal* function $\omega$ ?

Intuitively, it seems there are uncountably many such $\omega$, but in practice, can we prove the existence ?

Comment: [Cross-posted on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/138676/is-there-an-algebraically-normal-function-from-mathbbz2-to-0-1)